# MANOVA - huge matrices

Tags: cluster-analysis, anova

First, sorry by the tag as "ANOVA", it is about MANOVA (yet to become a tag...)

From the tutorials I found, all the examples use small matrices, following them would not be feasible for the case of big ones as it is the case of many studies.

I got 2 matrices for my 14 sampling points, 1 for the organisms IDs (4493 IDs) and other to chemical profile (190 variables).

The 2 matrices were correlated by spearman and based on the correlation, split in 4 clusters (k-means regarding the square euclidian clustering values), the IDs on the row and chemical profile on line.

The differences among them are somewhat clear, but to have it in a more robust way I want to perform MANOVA to show the differences between and within the clusters - that is a key factor for the conclusion, of course.

Problem is that, after 8h trying, could not even input the data in a format acceptable to the analysis.

The tutorials I found are designed to very few variables and even when I think I overcame that, the program says that my matrices can't be compared by their difference in length.

Each cluster has its own set of IDs sharing all same set of variables.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Diogo Ogawa

Answer (score 0):

If you have missing values in your data (which practically all data sets seem to contain) you can either remove those observations or you can create a model using those observations. Use the first approach if something about your methodology gives you conviction that there is something different about those observations. Most of the time, it is better to run the model using the missing values. In this case, use the general linear model instead of a balanced ANOVA model. The balanced model will struggle with those missing data.